# GetSection.Bind not working in .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am following a tutorial for implementing Azure Notification Hubs in my backend application (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms).
The tutorial focuses on using a API build in .NET Core, though my existing API is build in .NET 4.7.2 and for now it is to much of a hassle to rewrite the entire API.

Although I got most of it working in .NET 4.7.2, I am stuck on the following.
In the tutorial the following is being set for Dependency Injection:

```
services.AddOptions<NotificationHubOptions>()
        .Configure(Configuration.GetSection("NotificationHub").Bind)
        .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

I have rewritten this to:

```
services.AddOptions<NotificationHubOptions()
    .Configure(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NotificationHub").Bind)
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Sadly, I get a error on the Bind property that apparently does not exist:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.
```

Any clue how I can get this to work (or with the same functionality) in .NET 4.7.2?

The `NotificationHub` config setting is a setting stored in a secrets file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
```

The [ConfigurationBinder.Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind) method is part of that package.

Comment: As far as I can tell this package is not suitable for .NET 4.7, it also does not give me an overload on `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`